# Scraping something from a page which does not have a unique class

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I am trying to scrape different types of information for all players in the premier league, from transfermarkt page.

The relevant code is:

```
# Create empty list for player link
playerLink1 = []
playerLink2 = []
playerLink3 = []
#For each team link page...
for i in range(len(Full_Links)):
    #...Download the team page and process the html code...
    squadPage = requests.get(Full_Links[i], headers=headers)
    squadTree = squadPage.text
    SquadSoup = BeautifulSoup(squadTree,'html.parser')

    #...Extract the player links...

    playerLocation = SquadSoup.find("div", {"class":"responsive-table"}).find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})

    for a in playerLocation:
        playerLink1.append(a['href'])
        [playerLink2.append(x) for x in playerLink1 if x not in playerLink2] 

    #...For each player link within the team page...
        for j in range(len(playerLink2)):

    #...Save the link, complete with domain...
            temp2 = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + playerLink2[j]
    #...Add the finished link to our teamLinks list...
            playerLink3.append(temp2)

#Populate lists with each player

#For each player...
for i in range(len(playerLink3_u)):
    #...download and process the two pages collected earlier...
    playerPage = requests.get(playerLink3_u[i], headers = headers)
    playerTree = playerPage.text
    PlayerSoup = BeautifulSoup(playerTree,'html.parser')

#...find the relevant datapoint for each player, starting with name...
    tempName = PlayerSoup.find("div", {"class":"spielerdaten "}).find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
```

The problem is that in the last line, "tempName" (which is wrong), I do not have any class to find the the name of the soccer player.

This is the link for a player https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ederson/profil/spieler/238223

Any tips for how I can extract data, from this HTML code, as I need more data from the same place in addition to the name?

Comment: provide the code that playerLink3_u list, and what your expected out put is

Comment: the page is dynamic. You'll have to use Selenium to allow the page to rnder first. Or see if you can find it in the XHR

Comment: playerLink3_u list has alle the links for all the player pages. I want to find different information for each player in the list. Posted the code in the main question now

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic and rendered after the initial request. You'll have to access the data through an api (if available), or use a browser simulation like Selenium to open the page, let it render, and then pull the html:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

playerPage = driver.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ederson/profil/spieler/238223')
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                                   0                          1
0                         Full name:  Ederson Santana de Moraes
1                     Date of birth:               Aug 17, 1993
2                    Place of birth:                Osasco (SP)
3                               Age:                         26
4                            Height:                     1,88 m
5                       Citizenship:            Brazil Portugal
6                          Position:                 Goalkeeper
7                              Foot:                       left
8                      Player agent:                  Gestifute
9                      Current club:            Manchester City
10                           Joined:                Jul 1, 2017
11                 Contract expires:                 30.06.2025
12  Date of last contract extension:               May 13, 2018
13                        Outfitter:                       Nike
14                     Social media:                        NaN
```

Comment: Hi ok
can I do a for loop for each player in this way i.e. put "playerLink3_u" list inside driver.get, and to it for each player. After that extract all the data I need into these specific lists?

Name = []
Team = []
Age = []
Apps = []
Agency = []
Foot = []
Market_Value = []
Position = []
Joined_Date = []
Contract_expiration = []
Place_birth = []

Comment: I am also having trouble with downloading selenium and the chromdriver on my mac...

Comment: Yes. you would just loop through the links. As far as pulling out the exact data you want, looking into how to manipulate the dataframe with pandas. You might also need to pull in and append additional tables that is returned by `.read_html()`

Comment: I cant find the path to the webdriver. Keep getting the message:
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver ' executable needs to be in PATH.

Path on my mac is: /Applications/chromedriver

Do not understand Why.....

Comment: @Haroon, did you download chromedriver?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the Chromedriver, but the path does not work

Comment: You also installed Selenium, correct? And where is chromedriver.exe file on your system? and what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a real solution for your case but maybe you could use the xpath of the element instead of it's class.
The Xpath is the path of the HTML code to the very specific element. So, in case the name of the player is in the same position of the HTML script in every page, then you can **scrape** that element every time

To find the xpath in Firefox you have to find the element in inspector mode, right click it -> copy -> Xpath

Comment: I have not used Xpath before. Can I use it in Chrome?
If so, which package is it?
Also, given that the name is in the exact same place on every player page, I can loop it for alle the players?

Comment: I never use chrome but I guess you can use it. In a quick search I found how (https://testerlive.wordpress.com/2016/07/02/how-to-search-by-xpathcss-in-chrome-developer-tools/. What do you mean by packages? You have to search if BeautifoulSoup support Xpath but I am pretty sure they do. The lxml library does for sure. If the Xpath is the same for all names yes you can keep it as a variable and loop with it.